# how to differentiate from number and char when i read a line in c# as array of string

Tags: c#, arrays

i  read a line for example " DHAP::Glyc3P : 1.546 DHAP + 0.656 NADH = 1 Glyc3P ." from a .txt file and split word by space then save in an array of strings as follow

```
while((line = DOC.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    List<string> linestring = new List<string>();
    string[] words = line.Split(' ');
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        linestring.Add(word);

    }
}
```

now i need add number (for example 1.546 ) in a table and other strings (DHAP) in the other table!
and i don't know how to do it!!

Comment: A bit more context please: What's important for you? The whole string or just the "addition" (the part between the colon and the equal sign)?

Comment: The most flexible way would be to branch depending on a regular expression that defines what numbers and words look like. A simple way would be to use "tryparse" to convert to a number, and if it is false assume it was a string.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Double.TryParse` for every string, if the method succeeds then it is a `double` number so you can process it as you want to process (numbers), and if it doesn't succeed it is a `string`, process it as a string.

```
double val;
foreach (string word in words)
{
   if(Double.TryParse(word, out val)
   {
      // add val to numbers table
   }
   else
   {
      // add word to strings table
   }

}
```

For example:

```
while((line = DOC.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    List<string> linestring = new List<string>();
    List<double> numbers = new List<double>();
    double val;

    string[] words = line.Split(' ');
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        if(Double.TryParse(word, out val)
        {
            numbers.Add(val);
        }
        else
        {
            linestring.Add(word);
        }    
    }
}
```